# What is the numpy equivalent of random.sample?

Tags: python, numpy

I want to randomly choose 2 elements out of a list.

```
>>> import random
>>> random.sample(["foo", "bar", "baz", "quux"], 2)
['quux', 'bar']
```

But I want to use a `numpy.random.Generator` to do it, rather than using Python's global random number generator. Is there a built-in or easy way to do this?

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> gen = np.random.default_rng()
>>> ???
```

[edit] the point is to make use of `gen` which allows you to seed it for reproducibility. I realize the same can hypothetically be accomplished by re-seeding global generators, but I specifically want to use `gen`, a local generator, rather than relying on global generators.

Comment: Why not use `myrandom = random.Random(seed)` and then `myrandom.sample(...)`? Doesn't that accomplish your goal as well?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you really want to do it from the `numpy.random.Generator`:

```py
import numpy as np
gen = np.random.default_rng()
gen.choice(["foo", "bar", "baz", "quux"], 2, replace=False)
```

Note that `np.random.choice` selects *with replacement* by default (i.e. each item can be sampled multiple times), so turn this off if you want an equivalent method to `random.sample` (credit: @ayhan).

Comment: You also need `replace=False` for it to be random.sample's equivalent.

Comment: Ah, I don't use `random` often; I'll edit that note in.

Answer (score 1):

The use of np.random.choice, as suggested above, is indeed equivalent if you are sampling from one-dimensional data (such as a list of numbers or strings).

However,

```
a = [(1,2),(1,4), (2,3), (1,7)]
np.random.choice(a,2)
```

will produce an error. Your equivalent, in this case, is

```
[a[i] for i in np.random.choice(range(len(a)),2, replace=False)]
```

As commented above, it may be better to use the good old random.sample().